# Count number of rows per group in pandas datafreame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like so:

```
   canopy  speed
0       1    3.3
1       2    3.3
2       2    3.1
3       2    3.1
4       2    3.1
5       2    3.0
6       2    3.0
7       2    3.5
8       2    3.5
```

I want to count the number of rows (observations) for each combination of `canopy` and `speed` and plot it. I expect to see in the plot something like that:

```
canopy = 2:

3.3   1
3.1   3
3.0   2
3.5   3
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['canopy'].eq(canopy),'speed'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```py
df.groupby('canopy')['speed'].value_counts().unstack('canopy').plot.bar()
```

[image]

This gives you some options, for example normalizing within each group (to get frequency instead of count):

```py
(df
 .groupby('canopy')['speed']
 .value_counts(normalize=True)
 .unstack('canopy').plot.bar()
)
```

[image]

And, of course, you could control the rounding of the `speed` values (as @QuangHoang rightly mentioned: not a good idea to group on floats --to which I would add: without some rounding):

```py
(df
 .assign(speed=df['speed'].round(0))
 .groupby('canopy')['speed']
 .value_counts()
 .unstack('canopy').plot.bar()
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.canopy.eq(2).groupby(df['speed']).sum()
```

Output:

```
speed
3.0    2
3.1    3
3.3    1
3.5    2
Name: canopy, dtype: int64
```

**Note** it's really not a good idea to group on floats.